# Elasticsearch does not found an existing document using a the DSL

Tags: elasticsearch

I dont know why, using the [URI Search](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/2.2/search-uri-request.html) way to search a document is returning the right document, but the document is not found if I use the [API DSL](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/2.2/query-dsl.html).

To reproduce the issue:

Without any index created, I insert this document:

```
curl http://localhost:9299/integrationtest-index/searchable/ID_XXXX2 -d '{ "ref" : "XXXX2", "field1" : "value1" }'
```

So the index is created automatically with the default mapping (type searchable):

```
curl http://localhost:9299/integrationtest-index?pretty
{
  "integrationtest-index" : {
    "aliases" : { },
    "mappings" : {
      "searchable" : {
        "properties" : {
          "field1" : {
            "type" : "string"
          },
          "ref" : {
            "type" : "string"
          }
        }
      }
    },
    "settings" : {
      "index" : {
        "field1" : "value1",
        "ref" : "XXXX2",
        "number_of_shards" : "5",
        "creation_date" : "1466780216631",
        "number_of_replicas" : "1",
        "uuid" : "GBj2VF-wQy6JP74AqoIn5g",
        "version" : {
          "created" : "2020099"
        }
      }
    },
    "warmers" : { }
  }
}
```

This query return one document:

```
curl http://localhost:9299/integrationtest-index/searchable/_search?q=ref:XXXX2
```

But this other query response that does not exist:

```
curl -XPOST http://localhost:9299/integrationtest-index/searchable/_search/exists -d '
{
 "query":  {
       "term" : {
         "ref" : "XXXX2"
       }
     }  
 }'
```

Why the last query said that the document does not exist?

Environment:

- ElasticSearch 2.2.0
- Ubuntu 16.04 LTS
- OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_91-8u91-b14-0ubuntu4~16.04.1-b14)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have the same problem every few months, so I decided response myself and share my stupids errors.
By default, elasticsearch use **index:analyzed**, so the query with term does not found any document.
If you use the [URI Search way](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/2.2/query-dsl.html), elasticsearch is executing a [query_string](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-query-string-query.html) and not a term query.

This query is working:

```
curl -XPOST http://localhost:9299/integrationtest-index/searchable/_search/exists -d '
{
 "query":  {
       "match" : {
         "ref" : "XXXX2"
       }
     }  
 }'
```

More information in the documentation, in the section [Why doesn’t the term query match my document?](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/2.2/query-dsl-term-query.html)

Comment: Technically it's using a `query_string` query, not a `match` query.

Comment: @pickypg Thanks for the comment. Is it correct know?

Comment: Close enough, but you should probably also update the raw query itself.